# Changing '.CommandText' doesn't add new columns

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm fairly inexperienced with merging SQL into VBA, but for my next trick I wanted to arrange columns in a table to my liking.

```
Sub ExecuteQuery1()

Dim SQLstr As String

SQLstr = "select [Id], [Serviceman], [Status], [StatusTXT], [Inner_status], [Departure] , [EntryDate] " & Chr(10) & _
"from [AW_HD_S] order by [Id]"

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("HelpDesk Online").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = SQLstr
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("HelpDesk Online").Refresh
End Sub
```

Note: "where" statement is not necessary, since the table is designed specifically for our group

The table consists of ~50 columns, and I obviously don't need all of them.

Goal:
Have one SQL connection in worksheet named "DON'T YOU DARE TOUCH THIS", and by commandbuttons/userforms in other sheets be able to gather different summaries of data.

Now, while manipulating the SQLstr variable allows me to download the data I need, I don't need **all** of that data. Just, let's say, 7 or 8 columns.

First (minor) problem:
Excel seems to ignore the order of columns in my SELECT statement. Instead of order above, it **does** show the columns I want, but not in the order I want, but instead, in the order they appear in the table when I use SELECT *
I could deal with that, but if there's a way to fix it, it would be much more intuitive to force the order of columns I want.

Second (major) problem:
It looks like I can't add more rows with changing .CommandText and refreshing. For example:
1. SELECT * returns 50-something columns
2. I change * to, e.g., six columns
3. Table in Excel shows six columns, in its own order
4. I change CommandText to 15 columns, or to *
5. Table only shows six columns.

Now this is really troublesome, because I would like to use one and the same connection to execute different SQL commands and receive various amounts of columns.

What should I use instead of changing CommandText and refreshing connection to achieve that, or how to convince Excel to show the amount of columns I want?

Comment: For the display order, try something like this, `select column2 c2, column1 c1 etc` for a pair of columns that are in the opposite order in your table.  If they display in the correct order, make the aliases the same as the field names and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right-clicking the table, choosing Table and then External Data Properties. Then uncheck Preserve Column Sort/Filter/Layout:

[image]

Comment: Simple solutions are the best! Thanks, I doubt I'd ever think of it.